# Gluu Server continuously giving me 503 error - Service Unavailable

Tags: amazon-ec2, server, redhat, gluu

I have EC2 instance (Redhat 7.* 64 bit) and I have installed gluu-server-3.0.1 on that ec2 instance.
I followed this tutorial to install the gluu-server on the ec2 instnce 
[Gluu-server installation (official)](https://gluu.org/docs/ce/latest/installation-guide/install/)

I installed carefully following each and every step listed there on above link. Every step and command of the installation process was success (No problem with installation).

Finally when I visit the gluu-server link it redirects me to the correct link automatically. I visit **http://example.com** redirect me to **https://example.com/identity** but the gives me error 503.

Error

> The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to
>   maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to post this question on the [Gluu Support forum](https://support.gluu.org), you're more likely to get a response from the team.

Comment: Thank you very much sir. I am going to post now.

Answer (score 0):

Please increase ram and storage of your ec2 and try it.(If Gluu server required 4GB then go for 8GB EC2 instance and allot 6GB to Gluu server)